# Matching word without dot with Python regex

Tags: python, regex, grouping, cpu-word

I have a line in a file which can have below 2 formats:

```
/begin MEASUREMENT XXX.YYYY "Status ASC"
```

and

```
/begin MEASUREMENT XXXX "Status ASC"
```

I want to write an expression which **doesn't match** the first format but **can match** the second format and can give me XXXX from second format.

I tried below expression but couldn't get desired result:

```
/begin\s+MEASUREMENT (\w+)
```

What changes can I make in my regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may require a whitespace after `\w+`:

```
/begin\s+MEASUREMENT (\w+)(?!\S)
/begin\s+MEASUREMENT (\w+)(?=\s|$)
/begin\s+MEASUREMENT (\w+)(?:\s|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ncfrLi/1) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%2Fbegin%5Cs%2BMEASUREMENT%20(%5Cw%2B)(%3F%3D%5Cs%7C%24)):

[image]

The `(?!\S)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if the next char is not a non-whitespace. It is equal in meaning to `(?=\s|$)`, a positive lookahead that requires a whitespace or end of string immediately to the right of the current location. `(?:\s|$)` is a consuming variation of the latter regex (i.e. the whitespace, if matched, will land in the whole match), but since you are capturing the word before, it should not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! Can you please explain the meaning of (?!\S) , (?=\s|$) and (?:\s|$) ?

Comment: Gosh I didn't know about Regulex, that's a nice tool! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of a word boundary `\b` and a negative lookahead `(?!` to assert what is on the right is not a dot:

```
/begin\s+MEASUREMENT (\w+)\b(?!\.)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hvn7xa/1)